# How can I group time by hour or by 10 minutes?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, group-by

Like when I do

```sql
SELECT [Date]
  FROM [FRIIB].[dbo].[ArchiveAnalog]
  GROUP BY [Date]
```

How can I specify the group period? I'm using MS SQL 2008.

I've tried this, both with `% 10` and `/ 10`.

```sql
SELECT MIN([Date]) AS RecT, AVG(Value)
  FROM [FRIIB].[dbo].[ArchiveAnalog]
  GROUP BY (DATEPART(MINUTE, [Date]) / 10)
  ORDER BY RecT
```

Is it possible to make Date output without milliseconds?

Comment: I know you have an answer but what is the DATATYPE of the date column you're working with?

Comment: [All much easier in SQL Server 2022](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76813191/73226)

Answer (score 273, accepted):

finally done with

```
GROUP BY
DATEPART(YEAR, DT.[Date]),
DATEPART(MONTH, DT.[Date]),
DATEPART(DAY, DT.[Date]),
DATEPART(HOUR, DT.[Date]),
(DATEPART(MINUTE, DT.[Date]) / 10)
```

Comment: I made it `ROUND((DATEPART(MINUTE, DT.[Date]) / 5),0,1) * 5`, so that when I look at the data it's correlated with the nearest time slot

Comment: Year, month and day can be simplified to `DATE(DT.[Date])`.

Comment: @Keelan Doesn't work for me - however CONVERT(date, DT.[Date]) does.

Comment: `datepart(hour, workingPolicy.workingHours)/2.0` gives `1.5` while `datepart(hour, '1900-01-01 09:00:30.000')/2.0` gives `4.5` , i don't understand why? **Note:workingPolicy.workingHours=1900-01-01 09:00:30.000**. please help

Comment: Took me a while before I realized you weren't listing possible `DATEPART` options you could use but that you have to use all of the `DATEPART`'s

Answer (score 137):

### Short and sweet

```sql
GROUP BY DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '2000', date_column) / 10
```

With heavy acknowledgements to [Derek's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31157827/241211), which<sup>1</sup> forms the core of this one. **If you're on SQL Server 2022+,** go straight to [Martin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76813191/241211).

### Practical usage

```sql
SELECT   DATEADD(MINUTE, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '2000', aa.[date]) / 10 * 10, '2000')
                                                             AS [date_truncated],
         COUNT(*) AS [records_in_interval],
         AVG(aa.[value]) AS [average_value]
FROM     [friib].[dbo].[archive_analog] AS aa
-- WHERE aa.[date] > '1900-01-01'
GROUP BY DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '2000', aa.[date]) / 10
-- HAVING SUM(aa.[value]) > 1000
ORDER BY [date_truncated]
```

### Details and extra commentary

#### Bin interval size

The `MINUTE` and `10` terms can be changed to **any [`DATEPART`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datepart-transact-sql) and integer,**<sup>2</sup> respectively, to group into different time intervals. For example, `10` with `MINUTE` is ten minute intervals; `6` with `HOUR` is six hour intervals.

If you change the interval a lot, you might benefit from declaring it as a variable.

```sql
DECLARE @interval int = 10;

SELECT   DATEADD(MINUTE, DATEDIFF(…) / @interval * @interval, '2000')
…
GROUP BY                 DATEDIFF(…) / @interval
```

#### Value type

The actual values being grouped are a set of relative offsets from `2000-01-01 00:00`. This means data sources over long time intervals are fine. Some other answers have collision between years.

Multiplying the `GROUP BY` expression by the interval size and wrapping it in a `DATEADD` invocation will **return you a `DATETIME` value.** Including it in the `SELECT` statement will give your output a single column with the truncated timestamp. See the "Practical Usage" example above.

#### Shifting the label for the bin interval

The division (`/`) operation after `DATEDIFF` truncates values to integers (a `FLOOR` shortcut), which yields the *beginning* of time intervals for each row in your `SELECT` output.

If you want to label each row with the *middle* or *end* of its interval, you can tweak the division in the second term of `DATEADD` with the bold part below:

- End of interval: `…) / 10 * 10` **`+ 10`** `, '2000')`, credit to [Daniel Elkington](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5740181/daniel-elkington).
- Middle of interval: `…) / 10 * 10` **`+ (10 / 2.0)`** `, '2000')`.

If you want to *round your intervals inward* such that each timestamp represents half an interval before and half an interval after it, use something like this:

```sql
DATEADD(MINUTE, ROUND(1. * DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '2000', date_column) / 10, 0) * 10, '2000')
```

Note the `1.` to do untruncated division instead. You will need to modify your `GROUP BY` to match, and you may want to use the whole `ROUND(…)` expression to avoid any unexpected float rounding.

#### Date math trivia

`'2000'` is an "anchor date" around which SQL will perform the date math. Most sample code uses `0` for the anchor, but [JereonH](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20047/jeroenh) discovered that you encounter an integer overflow when grouping more-recent dates by seconds or milliseconds.<sup>3</sup>

If your data spans centuries,<sup>4</sup> using a single anchor date in the `GROUP BY` for seconds or milliseconds will still encounter the overflow. For those queries, you can ask each row to anchor the binning comparison to its own date's midnight.

Use one of the two replacements instead of `'2000'` wherever it appears in the query:

- `DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, aa.[date]), 0)`
- `CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(DATE, aa.[date]))`

Your query will be totally unreadable, but it will work.

---

<sub><sup>**1**</sup> I realized several years after posting that my code could be simplified to *nearly* the same as [Derek's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31157827/241211).</sub>
<sub><sup>**2**</sup> If you want all `:00` timestamps to be eligible for binning, use an integer that your `DATEPART`'s maximum can evenly divide into.<sup>5</sup> As a counterexample, grouping results into 13-minute or 37-hour bins will skip some `:00`s, but [it should still work fine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66742564/241211).</sub>
<sub><sup>**3**</sup> The math says 2<sup>32</sup> ≈ 4.29E+9. This means for a `DATEPART` of `SECOND`, you get 4.3 billion seconds on either side, which works out to "anchor date ± 136 years." Similarly, 2<sup>32</sup> milliseconds is ≈ 49.7 days.</sub>
<sub><sup>**4**</sup> If your data actually spans centuries or millenia and *is still accurate* to the second or millisecond… congratulations! Whatever you're doing, keep doing it.</sub>
<sub><sup>**5**</sup> If you ever wondered why our clocks have a 12 at the top, reflect on how [5 is the *only* integer](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1iYPs9-9YWyOGVQ26vyQHKJMg6Svbht3Yhy0NMFOQ27g/edit) from 6 (half of 12) or below that is not a factor of 12. Then note that 5 × 12 = 60. You have *lots* of choices for bin sizes with hours, minutes, and seconds.</sub>

Comment: To round UP to the nearest 10 minutes you can do
`GROUP BY DATEADD(MINUTE, (DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0, date_column) / 10 * 10) + 10, 0)` (and the same in the SELECT clause).

Comment: for SECOND as DATEPART I get an error message  (`The datediff function resulted in an overflow. The number of dateparts separating two date/time instances is too large. Try to use datediff with a less precise datepart.`). It seems that MINUTE is the smallest datepart you can use with this approach.

Comment: @jeroenh, you are correct. I have added a section to talk about that. tldr: Change the `0` to `'2000'` (quotes are important!) and try `SECOND` again.

Comment: @Michael This technique works great, but I did notice that if a given slice has a zero count, there is no corresponding row in the result set.

Comment: @howcheng Indeed. To do that, you could right-join against a table of all the possible intervals. You can generate one with a `cursor`, but I feel that's out of scope for the question.

Answer (score 23):

In T-SQL you can:

```
SELECT [Date]
  FROM [FRIIB].[dbo].[ArchiveAnalog]
  GROUP BY [Date], DATEPART(hh, [Date])
```

or

by minute use `DATEPART(mi, [Date])`

or

by 10 minutes use `DATEPART(mi, [Date]) / 10` (like Timothy suggested)

Comment: GROUP BY [Date], DATEPART(hh, [Date]) is a mess , not ?

Comment: @nCdy Should be all right, otherwise you get an error "...invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause"

Comment: How do you group by whole date and by hours in the same time? I'm just using Min Date .

Comment: if you use Min(Date) then of course you can take out the Date in the Group By.

Comment: Minutes divided by 10 will create grouping by 10 minute intervals, which i what's needed. Modulo 10 makes no sense.

Comment: If possible please amend your answer to use "DATEPART(mi, [Date]) / 10" instead of the above. This initially gave me the impression that SQL interprets the '%' sign as something other than modulo.  =>
`SELECT (27 / 10) = 2`  
`SELECT (27 % 10) = 7`

Answer (score 14):

For a 10 minute interval, you would

```
GROUP BY (DATEPART(MINUTE, [Date]) / 10)
```

As was already mentioned by tzup and Pieter888... to do an hour interval, just

```
GROUP BY DATEPART(HOUR, [Date])
```

Comment: but here I group minutes of 1980 year with minutes of 2011 :S I need to care about it.

Comment: Would % be the correct math? Wouldn't that create 10 groups. For example:

1 % 10 = 9
2 % 10 = 8

It wouldn't even necessarily be the correct chronological grouping either.

I think just a normal divide would be correct. Unless % isn't a remainder divide in sql.

Comment: Minutes divided by 10 will create grouping by 10 minute intervals, which i what's needed.
Modulo 10 makes no sense.

Answer (score 9):

The original answer the author gave works pretty well. Just to extend this idea, you can do something like

```
group by datediff(minute, 0, [Date])/10
```

which will allow you to group by a longer period then 60 minutes, say 720, which is half a day etc.

Comment: What would be the MySQL query for the above ?

Comment: this one is definitely better than the accepted answer. 
one can also set an arbitrary date instead of 0, and make the resulting datediff smaller:
DATEDIFF(minute, CAST('2021-08-01' AS datetime), [Date])/10

Comment: @ChingizK. The `CAST` can be implicit. `DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '2021-08-01', [Date])/10` works fine.

Answer (score 8):

Should be something like

```
select timeslot, count(*)  
from 
    (
    select datepart('hh', date) timeslot
    FROM [FRIIB].[dbo].[ArchiveAnalog]  
    ) 
group by timeslot
```

(Not 100% sure about the syntax - I'm more an Oracle kind of guy)

In Oracle:

```
SELECT timeslot, COUNT(*) 
FROM
(  
    SELECT to_char(l_time, 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24') timeslot 
    FROM
    (
        SELECT l_time FROM mytab  
    )  
) GROUP BY timeslot
```

Answer (score 6):

For MySql:

```
GROUP BY
DATE(`your_date_field`),
HOUR(`your_date_field`),
FLOOR( MINUTE(`your_date_field`) / 10);
```

Answer (score 5):

For people on SQL Server 2022+ there is now a dedicated [`DATE_BUCKET`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/date-bucket-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) function that addresses this need.

Example usage

```
DECLARE @ArchiveAnalog TABLE 
(
[Date] DATETIME2 PRIMARY KEY,
Value FLOAT
)

INSERT @ArchiveAnalog 
VALUES 
    ('2000-01-01 16:20:00.000', 1),  --Bucket 1
    ('2000-01-01 16:22:53.250', 2),
    ('2000-01-01 16:29:59.999', 3),
    ('2000-01-01 16:31:53.250', 4),  --Bucket 2
    ('2000-01-01 16:36:53.250', 5)


SELECT  
        DATE_BUCKET (minute, 10, [Date] ) AS BucketedValue,
        MIN([Date]) AS RecT, 
        COUNT(*) AS BucketCount,
        AVG(Value) AS BucketAvg
FROM @ArchiveAnalog
GROUP BY DATE_BUCKET (minute, 10, [Date] )
ORDER BY DATE_BUCKET (minute, 10, [Date] )
```

| BucketedValue | RecT | BucketCount | BucketAvg |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2000-01-01 16:20:00.0000000 | 2000-01-01 16:20:00.0000000 | 3 | 2 |
| 2000-01-01 16:30:00.0000000 | 2000-01-01 16:31:53.2500000 | 2 | 4.5 |

If the underlying column is indexed this can also be [pretty efficient](https://sqlperformance.com/2022/10/t-sql-queries/date-bucket-datetrunc-improve-time-based-grouping)

[image]

Answer (score 4):

If you want to actually display the date, have a variable grouping, and be able to specify larger time frames than 60 minutes:

```
DECLARE @minutes int
SET @minutes = 90

SELECT
    DATEADD(MINUTE, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0, [Date]) / @minutes * @minutes, 0) as [Date],
    AVG([Value]) as [Value]
FROM [FRIIB].[dbo].[ArchiveAnalog]
GROUP BY
    DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0, [Date]) / @minutes
```

Answer (score 3):

```
declare @interval tinyint
set @interval = 30
select dateadd(minute,(datediff(minute,0,[DateInsert])/@interval)*@interval,0), sum(Value_Transaction)
from Transactions
group by dateadd(minute,(datediff(minute,0,[DateInsert])/@interval)*@interval,0)
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. You need to fully explain your answer, and what this adds to the other 10 answers already on the site.

Answer (score 2):

In SQLite, in order to group by hour, you can do:

```
GROUP BY strftime('%H', [FRIIB].[dbo].[ArchiveAnalog].[Date]);
```

and to group by each 10 minutes:

```
GROUP BY strftime('%M', [FRIIB].[dbo].[ArchiveAnalog].[Date]) / 10;
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution is to use a function to create a table with the date intervals and then join this table to the data I want to group using the date interval in the table.
The date interval can then be easily selected when presenting the data.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_MinuteIntervals]
    (
      @startDate SMALLDATETIME ,
      @endDate SMALLDATETIME ,
      @interval INT = 1
    )
RETURNS @returnDates TABLE
    (
      [date] SMALLDATETIME PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL
    )
AS
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @counter SMALLDATETIME
        SET @counter = @startDate
        WHILE @counter <= @endDate
            BEGIN
                INSERT INTO @returnDates VALUES ( @counter )
                SET @counter = DATEADD(n, @interval, @counter)
            END
        RETURN
    END
```

Comment: Using a cursor will be very very slow on large data sets.

Answer (score 1):

For SQL Server 2012, though I believe it would work in SQL Server 2008R2, I use the following approach to get time slicing down to the millisecond:

```
DATEADD(MILLISECOND, -DATEDIFF(MILLISECOND, CAST(time AS DATE), time) % @msPerSlice, time)
```

This works by:

- Getting the number of milliseconds between a fixed point and target time:
  `@ms = DATEDIFF(MILLISECOND, CAST(time AS DATE), time)`
- Taking the remainder of dividing those milliseconds into time slices:
  `@rms = @ms % @msPerSlice`
- Adding the negative of that remainder to the target time to get the slice time:
  `DATEADD(MILLISECOND, -@rms, time)`

Unfortunately, as is this overflows with microseconds and smaller units, so larger, finer data sets would need to use a less convenient fixed point.

I have not rigorously benchmarked this and I am not in big data, so your mileage may vary, but performance was not noticeably worse than the other methods tried on our equipment and data sets, and the payout in developer convenience for arbitrary slicing makes it worthwhile for us.

Answer (score 0):

```
select from_unixtime( 600 * ( unix_timestamp( [Date] ) % 600 ) ) AS RecT, avg(Value)
from [FRIIB].[dbo].[ArchiveAnalog]
group by RecT
order by RecT;
```

replace the two 600 by any number of seconds you want to group.

If you need this often and the table doesn't change, as the name Archive suggests, it would probably be a bit faster to convert and store the date (& time) as a unixtime in the table.

Answer (score 0):

I know I am late to the show with this one, but I used this - pretty simple approach.  This allows you to get the 60 minute slices without any rounding issues.

```
Select 
   CONCAT( 
            Format(endtime,'yyyy-MM-dd_HH:'),  
            LEFT(Format(endtime,'mm'),1),
            '0' 
          ) as [Time-Slice]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select dateadd(minute, datediff(minute, 0, Date), 0),
       sum(SnapShotValue)
FROM [FRIIB].[dbo].[ArchiveAnalog]
group by dateadd(minute, datediff(minute, 0, Date), 0)
```

Comment: Please provide some explanations when you answer a question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query. It makes one column. (references @nobilist answer)

```
GROUP BY CAST(DATE(`your_date_field`) as varchar) || ' ' || CAST(HOUR(`your_date_field`) as varchar) || ':' || CAST(FLOOR(minute(`your_date_field`) / 10) AS varchar) || '0' AS date_format
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option that provides a human readable start time of that interval (7:30, 7:40, etc).

In a temp table, it truncates seconds and milliseconds by using SMALLDATETIME, and then the main query subtracts any amount over the desired minute interval.

```
SELECT DATEADD(MINUTE, -(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '2000', tmp.dt) % 10), tmp.dt)
FROM (
    SELECT CAST(DateField AS SMALLDATETIME) AS dt
    FROM MyDataTable
) tmp
```

It can also be done in a single line of code, but it is not as readable.

```
SELECT DATEADD(MINUTE, -(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '2000', CAST(DateField AS SMALLDATETIME)) % 10), CAST(DateField AS SMALLDATETIME)) AS [interval] FROM MyDataTable
```