# SQL Server GROUP BY datetime ignore hour minute and a select with a date and sum value

Tags: sql-server, datetime, select, group-by

I have a table with two fields - `datetime` and `int`. I want to do a group by on the `datetime` only on the date ignoring the hour and minute. The `SELECT` statement should return a date that maps to the sum of the int of a single day.

Comment: accepting one of the answers would be nice (*only the asker can do that*)

Comment: See also [How to group time by hour or by 10 minutes ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5002661/how-to-group-time-by-hour-or-by-10-minutes/41944083#41944083)

Answer (score 174):

```
SELECT CAST(Datetimefield AS DATE) as DateField, SUM(intfield) as SumField
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY CAST(Datetimefield AS DATE)
```

Comment: This will only work in SQL Server 2008+ (when the Date datatype was introduced). If you're in 2005 or earlier, changing the cast to convert(convert(int, Datetimefield), datetime) should work.

Comment: I'm getting an error saying that 'Type Date is not a defined system type'.

Comment: @Steven - then see Derek's comment.  This is why it's a good idea to include your **VERSION** in the question.

Comment: @Derek this doesn't seem to work. A `select convert(convert(int, getdate()), datetime)` fails with wrong syntax error

Comment: sorry, convert(datetime, convert(int, getdate()))

Comment: SQL Server 2022 has a potentially more efficient method https://stackoverflow.com/a/76761752/73226

Answer (score 25):

As he didn't specify which version of SQL server he uses (`date` type isn't available in 2005), one could also use

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),date_column,112),SUM(num_col) AS summed
FROM table_name
GROUP BY CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),date_column,112)
```

Comment: In older versions like 2000/2005 varchar conversion for this need is slower than use of `DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, date_field),0)`

Answer (score 10):

I came researching the options that I would have to do this, however, I believe the method I use is the simplest:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), 
       DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, date_field),0) as dtgroup 
FROM TABLE 
GROUP BY DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, date_field),0) 
ORDER BY dtgroup ASC;
```

Comment: This will work in any version of SQL Server and is faster than using varchar conversions.

Comment: Could you clarify what is "dd"?  I don't understand what you are supposed to put in it.

Comment: "dd" is datepart equivalent to day. You can also use "day", "d" or "dd"

Comment: For future readers: In case you adopt this good solution to rounding in seconds you will get an int overflow. That can be corrected by starting not from date "0", but a fixed date in the past that won't be accessed. Perhaps use the start of the year 2K.

Answer (score 3):

-- I like this as the data type and the format remains consistent with a date time data type

```
;with cte as(
    select 
        cast(utcdate as date) UtcDay, DATEPART(hour, utcdate) UtcHour, count(*) as Counts
    from dbo.mytable cd 
    where utcdate between '2014-01-14' and '2014-01-15'
    group by
        cast(utcdate as date), DATEPART(hour, utcdate)
)
select dateadd(hour, utchour, cast(utcday as datetime)) as UTCDateHour, Counts
from cte
```

Answer (score 2):

Personally i prefer the format function, allows you to simply change the date part very easily.

```
     declare @format varchar(100) = 'yyyy/MM/dd'
     select 
        format(the_date,@format), 
        sum(myfield) 
     from mytable 
     group by format(the_date,@format) 
     order by format(the_date,@format) desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

For SQL Server 2022+ you can use [`DATETRUNC`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datetrunc-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16).

This has an advantage over the other methods in that it is able to take advantage of the fact that an index ordered by `datetime` is also ordered by `date` and can avoid a sort operation.

e.g. Compare the below

```
CREATE TABLE #T(
Datetimefield DATETIME,
intfield INT,
)

CREATE INDEX IX ON #T(Datetimefield) INCLUDE (intfield)

SELECT CAST(Datetimefield AS DATE) AS DateField,
       SUM(intfield)               AS SumField
FROM   #T
GROUP  BY CAST(Datetimefield AS DATE) 

SELECT DATETRUNC(DAY,Datetimefield) AS DateField,
       SUM(intfield)               AS SumField
FROM   #T
GROUP  BY DATETRUNC(DAY,Datetimefield)
```

[image]