# Group by date not working in sql server

Tags: sql-server

I have this query

```
SELECT TOP 1000 [lid]
      ,[userid]
      ,[datetime]
      ,[batch_id]
      ,[actionid]
      ,[pages]
      ,[group]
      ,[sitecode]
  FROM [mydb].[dbo].[tbl_recon_scan]
  GROUP BY CAST([datetime] AS DATE)
```

it seems not working with `group by`.
I have looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6054144/how-can-i-group-by-date-time-column-without-taking-time-into-consideration) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7417017/sql-server-group-by-datetime-ignore-hour-minute-and-a-select-with-a-date-and-sum) guides, I could not find solution.

Anyone can tell me my problem with the query?

Comment: do you  want this 

SELECT DISTINCT TOP 1000 [lid]
      ,[userid]
      ,CAST([datetime] AS DATE) 
      ,[batch_id]
      ,[actionid]
      ,[pages]
      ,[group]
      ,[sitecode]
  FROM [mydb].[dbo].[tbl_recon_scan]

Comment: You can't use columns in the select clause if they are not in the group by clause or an aggregating function (`sum`, `max` etc'). I know MySql allows it, but sql server does not.

Comment: ALWAYS share the error you are getting.

Comment: You query not Contain Aggregate function then you can't use GROUP BY clause

Comment: What output are you expecting? Why are you grouping by one column and displaying others?

Answer (score 0):

You don't use any aggregate functions in query. So it shows every individual record.

Visit these link:

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173454.aspx
- http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_functions.asp