# SQL how to sum events in one hour between two dates and show it in one row

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2005, view, count

I am developing a report with C# and SQL server 2005,
I have to only show how many hit we got in each hour. the table is very huge.
output should look like this:

```
Row# |     Date    |  Time  | Hit Count
-----------------------------
1    | 07/05/2012  |  8:00  |  3
2    | 07/05/2012  |  9:00  |  4
3    | 07/05/2012  |  10:00 |  0
4    | 07/05/2012  |  11:00 |  5
```

My table is look like this:

```
"HitTime":

07/05/2012 08:02:24
07/05/2012 08:12:21
07/05/2012 08:23:00
07/05/2012 09:01:00
07/05/2012 09:08:14
07/05/2012 09:12:31
07/05/2012 09:22:27
```

..etc
As you see in HitTime field I only have date and time, I need to show at same date, from for example 8:00 till 8:59 how many hit did I get, and it should be for all day, from very first second that day starts till very end second of the day.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to group time by hour or by 10 minutes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5002661/how-to-group-time-by-hour-or-by-10-minutes)

Answer (score 4):

```
DECLARE @current_date DATETIME

SET @current_date = '2012-05-07';

WITH    hours (hr) AS
        (
        SELECT  0
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  hr + 1
        FROM    hours
        WHERE   hr < 23
        )
SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY hr) AS rn,
        @current_date AS [date],
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), DATEADD(hour, h.hr, @current_date), 108) AS [time],
        COUNT(hs.hittime) AS hitcount
FROM    hours h
LEFT JOIN
        hits hs
ON      hs.hittime >= DATEADD(hour, h.hr, @current_date)
        AND hs.hittime < DATEADD(hour, h.hr + 1, @current_date)
GROUP BY
        hr
```

Comment: +1, but OP is using SQL Server 2005, which does not allow for a `DATE` type variable, and you can't declare and set it in the same statement.

Comment: @KM: seems AJAX poll time is too slow on SO :)

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
;WITH aggregation(hit_date, hit_time)
AS
(
SELECT DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, hittime), 0)
     , DATEPART(hour, hittime)
FROM test
)
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY hit_date, hit_time) AS rn
     , CONVERT(VARCHAR,hit_date,101) as [date]
     , CAST(hit_time AS VARCHAR) + ':00' as [time]
     , COUNT(*) as hit_count
FROM aggregation
  GROUP BY hit_date
         , hit_time
```

Comment: Quite right.  Missed the 10:00 row. And most of the text underneath the sample data.

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH hit_count AS(
select CONVERT(VARCHAR,hit_time,101)as [date], substring(convert(varchar,hit_time,108), 0, 4)+'00' as [time] from hit
)
select date,[time], count(*) as hit from hit_count group by [time],[date]
```

And if You want AM/PM then :

```
WITH hit_count AS(
select CONVERT(VARCHAR,hit_time,101)as [date], (substring(convert(varchar,hit_time,100), 12, 4)+'00'+substring(convert(varchar,hit_time,100),18,2)) as [time] from hit
)
select date,[time], count(*) as hit from hit_count group by [time],[date]
GO
```

Comment: Thanks Manish but I guess the result is not correct, I mean the hit counters are not correct(its too much). 1) Please explain the query a little for me for example what is 101 ? 2) how could I show the time as PM/AM or I even could use 24 hour also.

Comment: @Pouria I have edited my answer now you will get your desired output and show time in 24 hours formate, and talking about 101 or 108 in a query these are the datetime formate.http://www.sqlhub.com/2009/04/list-of-all-available-datetime-format.html might be this link is useful for you.