# In SQL, how can I count rows grouping into certain intervals, if I only know the length of those intervals?

Tags: sql, sqlite, group-by

Let's say that my first column is time. What I want is to be able to count the rows grouping them by an arbitrary time range, for instance: by day, by hour, by 20 minutes intervals, by 15 seconds etc.

Comment: Here is the answer that already solved; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5002661/how-to-group-time-by-hour-or-by-10-minutes

Answer (score 0):

Convert the timestamp into some appropriate number (here: number of seconds since the Unix epoch), then do an integer division by the number of seconds (which implicitly rounds down):

```
SELECT ...
GROUP BY strftime('%s', MyDate) / 15  -- or 20*60 etc.
```