# Query to get a set of data from a Table for 1st 10 mins

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have 3 columns in table which are Id(int) , Value(int) and Time(datetime). I want query that get data(s) for 1st 10 mins then 2nd set of 10 mins and continued on..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to group time by hour or by 10 minutes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5002661/how-to-group-time-by-hour-or-by-10-minutes)

Answer (score 2):

You can use

> DATEDIFF ( datepart , startdate , enddate )

Your Query should be like

```
SELECT id, value, Time FROM Table 
WHERE DATEDIFF(MINUTE, Time, GETDATE()) <= 10
```