# sql server: how to know how many transactions were made per hour?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to find a way (maybe with sys DB) to retrieve information of all the queries executed per hour on the user databases.
my client wants me to give him a daily report via SSRS of transaction per hour I would love to hear suggestions scanned the internet with no luck.

edit: im trying to understand where to get this information from its not about how to filter results per hour 
thanks

Comment: [Something like this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5002661/how-to-group-time-by-hour-or-by-10-minutes)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to group time by hour or by 10 minutes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5002661/how-to-group-time-by-hour-or-by-10-minutes)

Comment: hi no.. i want to know how many transactions \queries per hour are being executed on my databases.its not about how to group by hour its about where to take the info from. thanks for the reply

Comment: You might have more luck on [Stack DBA](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).  If you want to move the question, click *close* >> *off-top because* >> *This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network* >> *Stack DBA*.

Comment: Hi! I am sorry, must have been a misunderstanding. But the general idea is to have a table multiple colums with date, hour, minutes,...,query_count Then every hh:00, take the count of rows where hour=hh-1, and save the records into another table. All this shoud be in a TVF, UDF or a SP, where the main query is executed.

Comment: im sorry i dont understand what youre saying. i want to collect all the queries that are running on that instance and then count them per hour. how do i log them to a table?

Comment: from which table do i take that info?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always have a look through the following tables:

```
master.sys.dm_exec_sessions
master.sys.dm_exec_connections
master.sys.dm_exec_sql_text
```

Comment: These are not tables but DMVs but can you explain how can one use them to get transactions per hour? The first two gives you the ACTUAL state, what we have now, the third gives you the text of query for given plan handle, but where is statistical data?

Comment: you mean maybe creating a new table and sort of loging the connections from this to the other table? cause as the person above me said this are all for current sessions

Comment: Initially I was just suggesting this to be able to view current queries, you could log the data by Hour etc and create a statistical table for an SSRS report.

Answer (score 1):

i ended up finding this(with a few little changes)

### thanks everyone for your help this seems to work fine

```
create table #execution_count 
(time  datetime,
onhour int,
query nvarchar(max),
dbid int,
objectid int,
number int,
encrypted int,
text nvarchar(max)

)

insert into #execution_count 
SELECT deqs.last_execution_time AS [Time], (datepart(hour, deqs.last_execution_time)) as onhour, dest.text AS [Query], dest.*
FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS deqs
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(deqs.sql_handle) AS dest
where deqs.last_execution_time > getdate()-1 --and cast(deqs.last_execution_time  as datetime) between '%19:00:00%' and '%2018-01-16 21:00:00%'
and dest.dbid not in(1,2,3,4)
ORDER BY deqs.last_execution_time DESC


select onhour, count(*) as total_executes_per_hour  from #execution_count 
group by onhour
having count(*)>0
drop table #execution_count
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Perfmon` counters `Transactions/sec` and `Batch Requests/sec` or the same counters from DMV `sys.dm_os_performance_counters`.

You can read more on the first counter here: [ransactions/sec performance counter](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/4736c21e-5fb2-46e0-80b0-96e1c1973b9e/transactionssec-performance-counter?forum=sqldatabaseengine)

But please take a look at this video too: [he Transactions/sec counter has big blind spots](https://littlekendra.com/2017/05/08/sqlserverdatabases_totaltransactionssec-vs-sql-statisticsbatch-requestssec-video/) because may be you should opt for `Batch Requests/sec`.

Comment: hi im aware of the way via perfmon and extended events but as i said i need this for an ssrs report... so i need something that will run pretty often on the server.thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Make a job that will run every 5 minutes (1 minute, as often as you want) and collect these counter values to a table. Make a report over this table

Comment: asking (cause i never tried)- wouldnt it have an impact on the performance of the server?

Comment: We have such a job enabled for every 5 minutes, and it gather many more counters. Yes of course it's not gratis but there is no way to get periodic information and to have no impact

Comment: yeah im just afraid because this client's server is really critical and running perfom every min sounds like it can cause a problem. if it wasnt this client iwould probably do that as well

Comment: You can schedule it to run once per hour then

Comment: but then it wouldnt be accurate i need all of the queries from the entire day

Comment: Make it as frequently as you want and if later they will say that the server became slow you'll explain them that they need to choose: or to have accurate data or have no performance impact