# Qlikview count all the product in the last 12hours

Tags: sql, qlikview

Given that I have the following data:

[image]

I want to count the number of distinct product sold in the passed 8 hours, Suppose the time now is 26/10/2018 23:35:00.

The expected result should be as follows:

[image]

I am working in qlikview. I do not know how to do the expression to get what i want especially when it concern datetime. should i use aggreegate or count?

Thank you in advance for answering!

Comment: Kindly follow below link for this solution. [how-to-group-time-by-hour-or-by-10-minutes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5002661/how-to-group-time-by-hour-or-by-10-minutes)

Answer (score 0):

```
Kindly try this for required output 
    DECLARE @CURR_DATE DATETIME
SET @CURR_DATE=DATEADD(hour,0,'10/26/2018 23:30')

SELECT Product, count(category)
  FROM  Table_1 
where 
  AddedDate between  DATEADD(hour,-1,@CURR_DATE) and @CURR_DATE  
  GROUP BY Product,category,(DATEPART(hh, AddedDate))
```

Comment: This is an SQL syntax, not a Qlikview one.

Answer (score 0):

I would recomend to define a flag for each record in the script to avoid tricky and complicated set analysis that could easily break.

Assumming you LOAD the Datetime somewhere, I would add :

```
LOAD
...
Datetime,
If(Datetime > Today() - 8 / 24, 'Y', 'N') as SoldInLast8Hours
....
```

Having this new dimension will allow you to use a simple set analysis like :

```
Sum({<SoldInLast8Hours = {'Y'}>} 1)
```

Or

```
Count({<SoldInLast8Hours = {'Y'}>} DISTINCT EntryId)
```

If you have an unique id for each transaction row.