# How to fetch data one line per each 15 minutes from the last 24 hour in Laravel 5.8?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, setinterval, laravel-5.8

I'm trying to get logs from the last 24 hours for a chart I'm building.
I'm using **Laravel 5.8**.

I need 1 line **per every 15 minutes** for the chart to be accurate.

The current state is one line per hour, I can't think of out to turn it into 15 minutes.

*Please help me to make it work and make the code look as pretty as possible!*

```
public function getDataDay(&$data) {
    $data = $data->where('created_at', '>', Carbon::now()->subHours(23)->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'))
                  ->select('id', 'part_id', 'data', 'created_at')
                  ->selectRaw('HOUR(created_at) as hour')
                  ->groupBy('hour')
                  ->get();
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to group time by hour or by 10 minutes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5002661/how-to-group-time-by-hour-or-by-10-minutes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this, it  is what i use in mysql

```
->selectRaw('FROM_UNIXTIME(FLOOR( UNIX_TIMESTAMP(created_at)/900 ) * 900) AS quaterhour')
->groupBy('quaterhour')
```

Of Course if you have mire than one day, you have to group also by years , month and days