# How to fill in missing rows in a datatable

Tags: c#

I have a large datatable of values and a DateTime.  There should be a row for every five minutes of a day.  The problem is that there are rows missing.  How would I go about creating rows to fill in the gaps so that the DataTable is complete?

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to handle those gaps when querying / using the data. You don't tell what data there is with timestamps. But filling just timestamp and leaving all other fields NULL doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: As per @ex4, when fetching the data, place it e.g. into an array. Then, run a simple loop over every 5 mins of the day incrementing from a new `DateTime` in 5 minute chunks. If there is a record in your array, `continue`; otherwise, create it.

Comment: Or you can even do it when querying data from database. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5002661/how-to-group-time-by-hour-or-by-10-minutes

Comment: @zaitsman I've attempted to iterate through the datatable and create rows where there should be rows and it works to a point but then all of the results are just repeated at the end, I've added the code in the comment after this:

Comment: `DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Parse("2020-04-25 00:00:00.0000000");

        for (int i = 0; i <= (1440 / 5); i ++)
        {
            if (System.Convert.ToDateTime(table_today.Rows[i][0].ToString()) != dateTime)
            {
                DataRow nullRow = table_today.NewRow();
                nullRow[0] = dateTime;
                nullRow[1] = new int();
                nullRow[2] = new int();
                nullRow[3] = new int();
                table_today.Rows.InsertAt(nullRow, i);
            }
            dateTime = dateTime.AddMinutes(5);
        }`