# Convert 15min to 10min timeseries with hour constraint in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, time-series

I have a timeseries in a 15min format with four different variables. I need to convert this into 10min timeseries format. Due to some constraints, I need to do this in SQL which I agree is probably the worse choice language to do this in. I am convinced however that it is doable.

What I believe needs to be done is to divide each 15min data point into three 5min data point and then add every two 5min data point into a 10min data point. Done manually this gives me the correct results.

Not only do the 15min data points need to be converted but the actual data since it is in kWh.

- For a 15min period to get the true kWh, we need to divide the value by 4 as there are 4*15min data points in an hour.
- For a 5min period to get the true kWh, we need to divide the value by 8 as there are 8*5min data points in an hour.
- For a 10min period to get the true kWh, we need to divide the value by 6 as there are 6*10min data points in an hour.

This means that the "raw total" will be different but when divided they will be equal.

Below some sample DDL SQL that shows the initial table:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Temp15min') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Temp15min

CREATE TABLE #Temp15min
(
    Project_id INT,
    Project_name VARCHAR(25),
    Date_results DATETIME,
    Pplus INT,
    Pminus INT,
    Qplus INT,
    Qminus INT,
    Zone VARCHAR(2)
)

INSERT INTO #Temp15min (Project_id, Project_name, Date_results, Pplus, Pminus, Qplus, Qminus, Zone)
VALUES 
(1, 'USA_Project', '2020-01-09 00:00',9879, 7766, 3886, 6628, 'US'),
(1, 'USA_Project', '2020-01-09 00:15', 15420, 10969, 5743, 9568, 'US'),
(1, 'USA_Project', '2020-01-09 00:30', 8763, 6602, 5475, 512, 'US'),
(1, 'USA_Project', '2020-01-09 00:45', 6998, 1083, 277, 13360, 'US'),
(1, 'USA_Project', '2020-01-09 01:00', 14356, 275, 1580, 14184, 'US'),
(1, 'USA_Project', '2020-01-09 01:15', 22983, 6161, 7815, 6917, 'US'),
(1, 'USA_Project', '2020-01-09 01:30', 7653, 5080, 2742, 8086, 'US'),
(1, 'USA_Project', '2020-01-09 01:45', 276, 14977, 10318, 3485, 'US')
```

The end result table:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Temp10min') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Temp10min

CREATE TABLE #Temp10min
(
    Project_id INT,
    Project_name VARCHAR(25),
    Date_results DATETIME,
    Pplus INT,
    Pminus INT,
    Qplus INT,
    Qminus INT,
    Zone VARCHAR(2)
)

INSERT INTO #Temp10min (Project_id, Project_name, Date_results, Pplus, Pminus, Qplus, Qminus, Zone)
VALUES 
(1, 'USA_Project', '2020-01-09 00:00', 9879, 7766,3886, 6628, 'US'),
(1, 'USA_Project', '2020-01-09 00:10', 12650, 9368, 4815, 8098, 'US'),
(1, 'USA_Project', '2020-01-09 00:20', 15420, 10969, 5743, 9568, 'US'),
(1, 'USA_Project', '2020-01-09 00:30', 8763, 6602, 5475, 512, 'US'),
(1, 'USA_Project', '2020-01-09 00:40', 7881, 3843, 2876, 6936, 'US'),
(1, 'USA_Project', '2020-01-09 00:50', 6998, 1083, 277, 13360, 'US'),
(1, 'USA_Project', '2020-01-09 00:00', 14356, 275, 1580, 14184, 'US'),
(1, 'USA_Project', '2020-01-09 00:10', 18670, 3218, 4698, 10551, 'US'),
(1, 'USA_Project', '2020-01-09 00:20', 22983, 6161, 7815, 6917, 'US'),
(1, 'USA_Project', '2020-01-09 00:30', 7653, 5080, 2742, 8086, 'US'),
(1, 'USA_Project', '2020-01-09 00:40', 3965, 10029, 6530, 5786, 'US'),
(1, 'USA_Project', '2020-01-09 00:50', 276, 14977, 10318, 3485, 'US')
```

A sanity check to make sure numbers are correct from start to finish:

```
SELECT Project_id, Project_name, SUM(Pplus)/4 PplusTotal, SUM(Pminus)/4 PminusTotal, Sum(Qplus)/4 QplusTotal, Sum(Qminus)/4 QminusTotal, Zone FROM #Temp15min GROUP BY Project_id, Project_name, Zone
UNION ALL
SELECT Project_id, Project_name, SUM(Pplus)/6, SUM(Pminus)/6, Sum(Qplus)/6, Sum(Qminus)/6, Zone FROM #Temp10min GROUP BY Project_id, Project_name, Zone
```

Graphically the conversion goes something like this:

- Left table is the 15min data points => Raw Total/4
- Middle table is the 5min data points => Raw Total/8
- Right table is the 10min data points => Raw Total/6

[image: 15min to 5min to 10min]

I understand the complexity of the request so any help is greatly appreciated !

Comment: As best i can tell, this is word-for-word exactly the same as your previous question which you marked as answered.

Comment: Cleaned up my other post. I have an additional constraint on the actual data as well here. It was suggested I ask another question.