# MySQL - get average of temperature for every 6 hours

Tags: mysql, datetime, average, hour

I have `created_at` column in my table. Let's say data as follows-

[image]

I want to get the average of temperature of each 6 hour segment. Let's say time starts from first hour of the day. Thus, my rows will be like as follows-

[image]

*Note: I am able to get average of temperature of each hour using `HOUR FROM` of MySQL.*

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5002661/how-can-i-group-time-by-hour-or-by-10-minutes could be helpful

Comment: @Ahmet-Salman seems relevant to mine quest. Let's have a look. Thanks <3